# List reports in BI Publisher 11g Web Service

Tags: jakarta-ee, bi-publisher

Is there a way to list available reports in BI Publisher 11g using web service it provides (ReportService)? I don't find anything basing on the methods names, but maybe I am missing something. I tried googling something, but I mostly find tutorials on how to create BI Publisher reports. :/

Also, if this is not possible using web services, maybe there is some other way to do this programmatically from java ee application?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Web Service provided by BI Publisher has method named `getFolderContents`, which does the job all right. I didn't see it in the first place, because for some reason, SOAP UI didn't list it among available methods.